# Sizing a #2 pine beam to span 13 feet 6 inches

Tags: framing

I want to remove a portion of a center wall in a single story house that is a trussed roof with load carried on exterior walls.  Snow load would be 30 ppf.  The section of wall measures 13 feet 6 inches.  Will a 14 foot beam constructed of two 2 by 12's sandwiched around 3/4 inch plywood support the center of the trusses?  The wall should not be load bearing but I also want to avoid any sag in the spanned ceiling.

Comment: I don’t understand. If a single story house has roof trusses that has the roof load transferred to the exterior walls, what is the 14’ beam in the center of the house going to carry?

Comment: What is the exterior wall to exterior wall dimension? Is the lower horizontal member of the roof truss one and same as the ceiling joists? Do ceiling joists from each exterior wall extend just past this center partition wall in an overlapping manner?

Comment: You should employ a structural engineer / architect, and not rely on the internet due to insurance etc.